# Polygon creation in python

Tags: python, polygon

I'm having trouble finishing my code for creating my polygon. The goal is to be able to create any polygon, but I keep getting errors on my (def polygon), but everything else works. I know I need to try to put in the amount of sides and length I input in the beginning, but I just can't figure out how. The code allows me to select a number from the menu, and input the length and number of sides, but then after that it stops working and I get an error. Here is what I have:

```
import math
import turtle

print("MENU")


def main():
   print ("1. Polygon Fractal")
   print("2. Fractal Shell")
   print("3. Snowflake")
   print("4. Fractal Tree")
   print("5. Exit")
   x=input("Please select a number")
   if x=="1":
       z=input("Please input the number of sides")
       a=input("Please input length")
       polygon(z,a)


def polygon(n,l):
    f = (n - 2) * 180/n
    for i in range(n):
        t.forward(l)
        t.right(180 - f)


main()
```

Here is the error I keep getting after I input 1 for polygon and the length and sides:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Documents/polygon extra.py", line 27, in <module>
       main()
      File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Documents/polygon extra.py", line 17, in main
        polygon(z,a)
      File "/Users/isabelavaldes/Documents/polygon extra.py", line 21, in polygon
        f = (n - 2) * 180/n
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code does not elicit the given error.

Comment: I tried to correct the original posting as best I could; as given, the code failed on many indentation errors.  Please correct my guesses.

Comment: You seem to have a slight habit of asking questions then deleting them as soon as you have an answer. Just want to make sure you're aware that SO is supposed to be a repository of good questions and answers, *not* a quick way to get your homework done then remove all traces.

Answer (score 0):

the result of `input()` is a string. `z` is a string when you pass it to `polygon()`, so in the first line of `polygon` you are trying to subtract an integer (`2`) from a string (`n`).

Your code results in something like `"5" - 2` instead of `5 - 2`. That explains the `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`.

You can correct this by casting `z` (and `a`) to an integer with `polygon(int(z),int(a))`